# df.to_csv formatting issues on window

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function to save a dataframe with the format csv and where the user selects the path to save it. 
It works just fine on Mac but when I run the app on Windows, the output csv file is ugly. (everything is in the first row)

I have look around stackoverflow and tryed "wb" instead of "w" but it didnt do anything, as well as including "encoding="utf-8-sig", which did nothing either. 
I have found nothing about "write(df.to_csv), which I assume could be the issue. I am out of anything else to try.

here is what my code look like:

```
            def download_rep_report():
                f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='csv')
                f.write(replenishment_per_supplier.df5.to_csv(encoding='utf-8-sig'))

                if f is None:
                    message0 = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("telechargement", "Une erreur est survenue. Réessayez")
                else:
                    # df3.to_csv('replenishment_all_items.csv')
                    message = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("telechargement", "rapport de réapprovisionnement téléchargé")
```

I am wondering if someone ran in the same issue with df.to_csv and how I can get this to save the csv in the proper format. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try- `replenishment_per_supplier.df5.to_csv(f)` ?- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `with open('x.csv','w') as f: f.write(df.to_csv(encoding='utf-8-sig'))`.

Comment: that does not work

Comment: The docs for `DataFrame.to_csv` mention this for the `path_or_buf` parameter: _File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a string. If a file object is passed it should be opened with newline=’’, disabling universal newlines._ Try the suggestion for the `newline` parameter?